# Field Calculator If Statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else, syntaxerror

I am new to python and was trying to populate a decade field based on an if else statement on another field that contains parcel years.

The code block is below:

````
def ifBlock(Parcel_Year_Built, Decade_Grouping):
    if (Parcel_Year_Built < '1960' and > '0'):
        return "59 and earlier"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1960' and < '1970'):
        return "60s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1970' and < '1980'):
        return "70s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1980' and < '1991'):
        return "80s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1991'):
        return "Post Ban"```
````

and the code is:

```
ifBlock(!Parcel_Year_Built!,!Decade_Grouping!)
```

The error I get is:

```
  File "<string>", line 2
    if (Parcel_Year_Built < '1960' and > '0'):
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: second condition of the if statement should include your variable. For example,

if (Parcel_Year_Built < '1960' and Parcel_Year_Built > '0'):
    return "59 and earlier"

Comment: Ah. Thank you! That worked. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It is very unwise to attempt integer comparison using strings. You can get bizarre results based on character set codepoint order, not integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code with the following code block

```
def ifBlock(Parcel_Year_Built, Decade_Grouping):
    if (Parcel_Year_Built < '1960' and Parcel_Year_Built > '0'):
        return "59 and earlier"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1960' and Parcel_Year_Built < '1970'):
        return "60s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1970' and Parcel_Year_Built < '1980'):
        return "70s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1980' and Parcel_Year_Built < '1991'):
        return "80s"
    elif (Parcel_Year_Built >= '1991'):
        return "Post Ban"
```